# Unable to delete table row in expressjs mongoose

Tags: jquery, ajax, express, mongoose

front end button:

```
<button id="<%=camp.id%>" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger delete-camp " ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </button>
```

My ajax call to back end is:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.delete-camp', function () {
        let id = this.id;
        console.log(id);
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/camplist/delete',
              data: {'campid': this.id},
              success: function(response){
                  alert('Deleted');
                 
              },
              error: function(err){
                  console.log(err);
              }
    
          });
      });
    
    My route in backend : 
    exports.postDeleteCampaign = (req, res, next) => {
      Campaign.findByIdAndRemove({id:req.params._id}, (err) => {
         if (err) { return next(err); }
         req.flash('info', { msg: 'Campaign has been deleted.' });
         res.redirect('/campaign-list')
});
     };
```

Here my button is for deleting a row in a table. When i click button nothing happen. I have same button in some other page and that is working. can't figure it out. I tried mongoose `deleteOne` method but no use

Comment: when you say "nothing happens" ... what do you really mean? #1 did you check in the database and see that the document was actually deleted? #2 is the UI that does nothing? ... BTW, I would normally mark the document as "deleted" and not actually deleted, `$push` ing an event to a `events` array in the `Campaign` saying when was deleted, and have a `status = "deleted"` property that I would index so I can only show non deleted campaigns to the user, but keep all campaigns for analytics/logs/events/... proposes

Comment: Nothing in UI and in Database happens

Comment: I've answered a question this week about MongoDB and ended up creating a simple GitHub repository for it, I hope you can follow the code and fix your issue... I've added delete by event id (array item) and delete Story (delete a document from a collection) --> https://github.com/balexandre/so65351733